# Toggle animate() em DIVs na mesma posição

Tags: jquery, animação

Consegui fazer o efeito de exibir uma `div`, quando `hover`, que está oculta e abaixo da visível. Porém, o efeito fica meio "louco" quando eu fico movendo o mouse dentro do `container`. Alguém tem um solução? =|

[Código completo no JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Phellipe/Uj52b/)

Valeu!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar um [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), antes do `animate()`, exemplo:

```
$(this).stop().animate({
    top: "-200px"
}, 500);
```

Quando `stop()` é chamado em um elemento, a animação corrente é imediatamente interrompida. Se mais de uma animação é chamada no mesmo elemento, elas são colocados na fila de efeitos e a próxima animação não começará até que a primeira seja concluída, isso evita aquele efeito indesejado.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uj52b/1/)**